# How to track Multiple Purchase on a thank you page with Fackbook pixel

Tags: facebook, tracking-pixel

Ok so I'm programmatically generating the purchase pixel on my site on the thank you page and I can't find any docs as to if the following works:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version="2.0";n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,"script","https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js");
fbq("init", "##ID##"); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq("track", "PageView");
    fbq("track", "Purchase", {value: ##price##, currency: "USD"});
    fbq("track", "Purchase", {value: ##price##, currency: "USD"});
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=##ID##&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Will that generate 2 conversion events in the facebook system, or throw a misconfigured pixel?  Read all through their documentation and can't find anywhere if this will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that would throw an error. Are you trying to measure multiple orders or multiple products in a singular order?

Comment: Multiple products in a single order

Comment: In that case, you shouldnt need to generate two conversion events. instead do one where the value is the total order price

Comment: I was hoping to differentiate between our average item price as we have some small ticket things with upsells vs some significantly higher value products without them, and thats what the site owner wants to see in Facebook.

Comment: In that case, you can create a different conversion event in addition to Purchase and call it something like "LowValueItem". Then, in Facebook, you can create a Custom Conversion that fires if item in cart is less than certain value.